# database - functional dependencies

Tags: database-design, functional-dependencies

given a relational schema R(A,B,C,D,E,G)

with the set of functional dependencies:

```
F = {A->BC,C->BG,CD->E,G->D,E->B,CE->A,BH->E}
```

Can anyone explain to me how to find the relation between C and E? And between C and A?

Comment: Hi. "the relation between" doesn't mean anything. Please edit your post to use technical terms, properly. (Maybe you want to know whether the FD A -> A holds, etc?) While you're there, please edit your title to something that you could find when googling for an answer. Also please google 'stackexchange homework' & edit in some work you did.

Answer (score 1):

Given a relation schema with a set of functional dependencies, the phrase: “finding a relation between two attributes” is not clear. What is the relation between C and E? One should find if C determines E? Or if E determines C? Or if they belong to the same candidate key? Or what else?

For instance, assuming that you want to know if C determines E or viceversa, you could compute the closure of one of the two and find if the other belongs to this closure.

For instance, if E belongs to the closure of C (written C+), then we know that C -> E holds (that is, that the functional dependency C -> E can be derived from the set F of the given functional dependency). Or viceversa, if C belongs to the closure of E, then we know that E -> C holds.

The closure of a set of attributes can be computed with a simple algorithm that uses the dependencies available: we start with the set of attributes, and for each dependency such that the left part is included in the closure, and the right part is not included, we add the right part to the closure. For instance:

```
C+ = C  (we start with the attribute itself)
C+ = CBG (using C->BG, we add BG to the closure)
C+ = CBGD (using G -> D)
C+ = CBGDE (using CD -> E)
C+ = CBGDEA (using CE -> A)
```

No other dependency can be used, so we stop here and note that, since E belongs to the closure of C (actually C is a candidate key), C->E holds, while, calculating E+, we find that the closure is BE, so E does not determine C.